# can't access public enum Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, enums

Here is the code for the enum:

```
public enum Foo {
  case fooA(someParameter)
  case fooB(anotherParameter)
}
```

if I do this:

```
    var foo = Foo 
or
    var Foo.fooA(someParameter)
```

I get unresolved identifier. I can't call a switch with Foo either. what am I missing? Why would a public enum be different than a regular global enum?

Comment: `var foo = Foo.fooA(someParameter)`??

Comment: The (someParameter ) is a value or something. It's just that the enum has public in front of it, I can't access it at all. Why would public stop me from doing that?

Comment: If fixing the syntax error @MadProgrammer pointed out doesn't fix it (missing `foo = `), we will need more context. Are your two code snippets in the same file? The same module? The same package?

Comment: enum is in one swift file. trying to access it in another file.

Comment: I get 'use of unresolved identifier'

Comment: Okay, the enum while public is in a folder OUTSIDE of the main folder. I forgot how to access that.

Comment: So how did you access that enum? Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code for your enum is a bit off.

in TestEnum.swift:

```
public enum Foo {
    case fooA(someParameter : Int)
    case fooB(anotherParameter : Int)
}
```

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var aNewFoo = Foo.fooA(someParameter: 16)

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I was overthinking poorly. Creating a variable of Foo.self works in AppDelegate, but I get a warning of variable name not used.